# Faster way to choose a random post from reddit using PRAW in an asynchronous environment

Tags: python, asynchronous, optimization, praw

Is there fastest way to get a random post from the "hot" category of a chosen subreddit using PRAW because the code I have can take up to 3 seconds. I tried reducing the range with `randint` but it's not changing anything and it's not ideal since I'd like it to have a wider range.

I'm using [discord.py](/questions/tagged/discord.py) to get user's choice of the subreddit.

Best way I found so far:

```
async def on_message(message):
        reddit = connect_api() # Auth to the API
        sub = message.content[8:] # subreddit choice from user
        hot_results = reddit.subreddit(sub).hot()
        random_num = random.randint(1, 100)

        for i in range(0, random_num):
            random_post = next(x for x in hot_results if not x.stickied)
```

I also tried to append every posts to a list and then choose a random post from it but it's obviously even longer.

The internet connection should be quite well since I'm running it on a vps.

Answer (score 1):

I have my api connecting done outside of the command itself so that it loads when the bot is first turned on (might help with the speed)

```
reddit = praw.Reddit(client_id='CLIENT ID',client_secret='CLIENT SECRET',user_agent='USER AGENT')
```

This is how I do my random selection (I'm using the *secrets* module rather than random because of some compatibility issues but I don't think it changes the speed of the command much)

```
@client.command()
async def red(*args):
    posts = reddit.subreddit(args[0]).hot(limit=30)
    random_post_number = secrets.randbelow(30)
    for i,post in enumerate(posts):
        if i==random_post_number:
            await client.say(post.title)
            await client.say(post.url)
```

I've timed every request to multiple subreddits and the most it takes to load a "picture + title" from a post is
**.8 seconds**
 Hope some of this helped!